# How to add basic page content

Tags: nodes

I wanted to add basic page content but I cant see in add content  why it is? can anyone tell me how to create it now please?

Answer (score 0):

You need enable the basic page link in `admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation`. I think this might be the problem

[image]

Comment: i dont see any basic page menu in navigation, i could see only artical and other content types except Basic page

Comment: Check whether this url works for you /node/add/page

Comment: yes i could see list of content type created and artical etc, but basic page missing

Comment: what could be the reason?i dont know it has been deleted or not even?is there any way to create basic page now?:(

Comment: Check the permission. whether user has given the permission to create basic page

Comment: there is no basic page content only to give permission on permission page

Comment: is it possible to create new basic page content type with same functionalities

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have deleted Basic page content type , easiest solution could be creating the same type using Content type UI , it is easy this type has only a title and body and comments are off. PHP codes as body or text area , is not suggested in drupal but if you want to insert it in your body then [Code Filter Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/codefilter) will allow you to insert PHP.